# PowerShell Parameter in more than one ParameterSet returns ambigous error

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PS function, that should give an activate or deactivate command depending on the switch parameter specified.

I want $Active and $Inactive in two different parameter set, but I want to specify $InputFile or $Policy with $Active\$Inactive

```
function ModifyState (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="A")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="I")]
    [string]$InputFile,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="A")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="I")]
    [string]$Object,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="A")]
    [switch]$Active,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="I")]
    [switch]$Inactive

) {
    switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
    "A" {
        if ($InputFile) {
            foreach ($obj in (gc $InputFile)) {
                write-host "Activate $obj"
            }
        }
        else {write-host "Activate $Object"}
    }
    "I" {
        if ($InputFile) {
            foreach ($obj in (gc $InputFile)) {
                write-host "Deactivate $obj"
            }
        }
        else {write-host "Deactivate $Object"}
    }
    }
```

When I run the command without specify parameters or when I specify "too many parameters" I get error about ambigous parameter set.

Command:

```
ModifyState -InputFile .\temp.txt -Inactive -Active
```

Error:

```
ModifyState : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ ModifyState -InputFile .\temp.txt -Inactive -Active
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ModifyState], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,ModifyState
```

Question 1:
Is parameters code right?

Question 2:
Is there a way to return a default message when there's a parameter set ambiguity?

Hope I was clear and thank you in advance

db

---

Update 13/11/18
These are the examples of the commands that I want to give:

```
#Parameterset "I"
ModifyState -Object PARAMVALUE -Inactive
or
ModifyState -InputFile PARAMVALUE -Inactive

#Parameterset "A"
ModifyState -Object PARAMVALUE -Active
or
ModifyState -InputFile PARAMVALUE -Active
```

-Active and -Inactive must not given at the same time.
Also -InputFile and -Object must not given at the same time.

db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the updated requirements, you should be doing something like this:

```
function ModifyState (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = "Active-File")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = "Inactive-File")]
    [string]$InputFile,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = "Active-Object")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = "Inactive-Object")]
    [string]$Object,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = "Active-File")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = "Active-Object")]
    [switch]$Active,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = "Inactive-File")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = "Inactive-Object")]
    [switch]$Inactive
) {
    switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
        "A" {
            if ($InputFile) {
                foreach ($obj in (gc $InputFile)) {
                    write-host "Activate $obj"
                }
            }
            else {write-host "Activate $Object"}
        }
        "I" {
            if ($InputFile) {
                foreach ($obj in (gc $InputFile)) {
                    write-host "Deactivate $obj"
                }
            }
            else {write-host "Deactivate $Object"}
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation**
With the exclusion between the "object" parameters and the "active" parameters, you will need 4 different parametersets to fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

With you example you shared with us, the following would be valid parametersets:

```
#Parameterset "I"
ModifyState -InputFile PARAMVALUE -Object PARAMVALUE -Inactive

#Parameterset "A"
ModifyState -InputFile PARAMVALUE -Object PARAMVALUE -Active
```

If you only plan on having those 2 parametersets and you have some parameters that should be valid for both, you actually don't need to declare them in the parametersets - unless the should behave **differently**.

So you example could be written like this:

```
function ModifyState (    
    [string]$InputFile,    
    [string]$Object,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = "A")]
    [switch]$Active,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = "I")]
    [switch]$Inactive) {
    switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
        "A" {
            if ($InputFile) {
                foreach ($obj in (gc $InputFile)) {
                    write-host "Activate $obj"
                }
            }
            else {write-host "Activate $Object"}
        }
        "I" {
            if ($InputFile) {
                foreach ($obj in (gc $InputFile)) {
                    write-host "Deactivate $obj"
                }
            }
            else {write-host "Deactivate $Object"}
        }
    }
}
```

If you plan on executing your function without any parameters, you need to provide a     `[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Default')]` section and provide default values for the parameters.

```
function ModifyState {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'A')]
    param(
        [string]$InputFile = "Filepath",
        [string]$Object,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = "A")]
        [switch]$Active = [switch]::Present,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = "I")]
        [switch]$Inactive) {
        switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
            "A" {
                if ($InputFile) {
                    foreach ($obj in (gc $InputFile)) {
                        write-host "Activate $obj"
                    }
                }
                else {write-host "Activate $Object"}
            }
            "I" {
                if ($InputFile) {
                    foreach ($obj in (gc $InputFile)) {
                        write-host "Deactivate $obj"
                    }
                }
                else {write-host "Deactivate $Object"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That would make it possible for you to run the function without parameters. The -Active will always be set and the -InputFile will have always point the to file you specify as the default value.

With all that in place - what would you have expected from the `ModifyState -InputFile .\temp.txt -Inactive -Active` ?

Either you should be using:

`ModifyState -InputFile .\temp.txt -Inactive`

or

`ModifyState -InputFile .\temp.txt -Active`

with the current parametersets you have defined.

Please update you question with more details about what you are trying to solve, so we can help you on your way.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear at all.
"ModifyState -InputFile .\temp.txt -Inactive -Active" was a try to understand what the function would return, but it's not what I want, because -Active and -Inactive must not given at the same time.
Also -InputFile and -Object must not given at the same time

What I want is:

#Parameterset "I"
ModifyState -Object PARAMVALUE -Inactive
or
ModifyState -InputFile PARAMVALUE -Inactive

#Parameterset "A"
ModifyState -Object PARAMVALUE -Active
or
ModifyState -InputFile PARAMVALUE -Active